# Make every string unique by appending counter

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of string and I want to make every string in that list unique by appending a number at the end of it. Also, it is case insensitive, so "apple" should be assumed the SAME as "Apple" or "apPlE"

For example:

```
List<string> input = new List<string>();
input.Add("apple");
input.Add("ball");
input.Add("apple");
input.Add("Apple");
input.Add("car");
input.Add("ball");
input.Add("BALL");
```

Expected output:

"apple", "ball", "apple2", "Apple3", "car", "ball2", "BALL3"

I need help to develop the logic to produce the output. Thank you.

> > Edited: I CANNOT have 0 and 1, the repeated string must start with 2, 3, 4...

Comment: would it still work if you had `apple0, ball1, apple2, Apple3, car4, ...`?

Comment: No, I cannot have 0 and 1, everything repetition has to start with 2

Comment: @C.J. I'm just saying, if all you need to do is make the strings unique, than you can just keep applying an incremented number to the end of each string.

Comment: @N4TKD I used the .contain function but first, it doesn't deal with case insensitive, second, I don't know how to make the loop to check when the repetition is more than twice]

Comment: @SamIam I wish I could have done that, but the requirement doesn't allow me to.

Comment: That's some weird requirement! But I think @L.B already answered your question.

Comment: This must be homework!  You should solve these problems yourself or you won't get better.

Comment: @MikkoViitala Indeed!

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey No, it is not. It is part of the government project that I'm working on. Their legacy database was so sh** that no SQL/PL can solve it. And I have to bring them into the .NET environment to transform them manually

Comment: Haha, ok well I can appreciate that.  "Good enuf for government work" as they say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var newList = input.GroupBy(x => x.ToUpper())
              .SelectMany(g => g.Select((s, i) => i == 0 ? s : s + (i+1)))
              .ToList(); 

var str = String.Join(", ", newList);
```

**EDIT**

```
var newList = input.Select((s, i) => new { str = s, orginx = i })
                .GroupBy(x => x.str.ToUpper())
                .Select(g => g.Select((s, j) => new { s = j == 0 ? s.str : s.str + (j + 1), s.orginx }))
                .SelectMany(x => x)
                .OrderBy(x => x.orginx)
                .Select(x => x.s)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: There's no way the professor is gonna accept these kinda mad linq skills as an answer.  I'll +1 you anyways for being so smartz

Comment: @L.B Thank you for your solution, but there is one down side, your code unintentionally sort the order alphabetically and I must remain the original sorting order.

Comment: If the `List original` is a `List<someClass>` with a `Name` member, you can simplify this even more. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rpresser/71b9ee973c946e21f4b3af653cb21cec)